# How to add CSS to all tds of a particular tr in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to add a css `{padding : 0px 8px 0px 2px}` to all td's of a particular tr. tr is like this:  `$('#' + rowid)`

Comment: did you go through jquery api/docs?

Comment: Yes. that's why i have used @Curt's idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#' + rowid).find("td").css("padding", "0px 8px 0px 2px");
```

---

- `$('#' + rowid)` gets the `tr` element.
- `.find("td")` gets all `td` elements nested in your `tr` element.
- `.css("padding", "0px 8px 0px 2px")` applies the relevant styles to your `td` elements.

Comment: @soham.m17 In which case try replicating the issue on jsfiddle and post a link here. It's most likely there is another issue. The code isn't being called, or `rowid` isn't the value you expect etc..

Comment: I am sorry. You and I both were right. I was manipulating in a wrong way. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('td', '#' + rowid).css('padding', '0px 8px 0px 2px');
```

Or better yet, put the `padding` in a class in your stylesheet and use `addClass` as it's a better separation of concerns.

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
$('.' + rowclass).find("td").css("padding", "0px 8px 0px 2px");
```

you can not use same `id` for more than one tag ,so you have to use `class` for that ,because tags can have same class but not same Id

Answer (score 1):

Try like below... it will work

```
var ele = '#' + rowid;
$(ele + " td").css('padding', '10px 8px 0px 2px');
```